# How to avoid decoding bytes to string all the time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, decode

There are some packages that returns values as bytes in my project. There is some configuration or environment variable to set so I don't need to decode bytes to string ever again? And if so, what is it?

Comment: Python 3 is strict on the distinction between string and bytes. Downgrade to Python 2.7 if it really bothers you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2 by default  can do what you want.

But let me advise: this is NOT what one really wants and that's why Python 3 does not do that automatically.

To convert bytes to str, you need to know the coding of the bytes:

`s = b.decode(coding)`

To convert str to bytes, you also need to know the desired coding:

`b = s.encode(coding)`

Python 2 assumed coding == 'ASCII' and thus worked for english / plain ASCII texts, but raised exceptions at runtime for everything else.

So, what you have to do is:

- decide whether something should be processed as text (in that case you use str) or as binary (then you keep bytes)
- decode early (after loading, receiving the bytes)
- process as str
- encode late (before saving, sending the bytes)

Nowadays utf-8 encoding is the most popular, so use that if you have no other requirements.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so. It is up to the packages as to how they return values in their methods.