# I was wondering if someone could explain to me .decode and .encode in hashlib?

Tags: encoding, decoding, sha256, sha, hashlib

I understand that you have a hex string and perform SHA256 on it twice and then byte-swap the final hex string. The goal of this code is to find a Merkle Root by concatenating two transactions. I would like to understand what's going on in the background a bit more. What exactly are you decoding and encoding?

> > > import hashlib
> > >
> > > transaction_hex = "93a05cac6ae03dd55172534c53be0738a50257bb3be69fff2c7595d677ad53666e344634584d07b8d8bc017680f342bc6aad523da31bc2b19e1ec0921078e872"
> > >
> > > transaction_bin = transaction_hex.decode('hex')
> > >
> > > hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(transaction_bin).digest()).digest()
> > >
> > > hash.encode('hex_codec')
> > >       '38805219c8ac7e9a96416d706dc1d8f638b12f46b94dfd1362b5d16cf62e68ff'
> > >
> > > hash[::-1].encode('hex_codec')
> > >       'ff682ef66cd1b56213fd4db9462fb138f6d8c16d706d41969a7eacc819528038'

Comment: What protocol are you trying to describe here? What you're referring to doesn't sound normal.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: You encode bytes (integers) to a string of lower case ASCII characters from `[0-9a-f]`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51227998/342544) might be helpful?

Comment: @BenStolman Oh, is this a Bitcoin thing? Please include that information in the question -- right now you haven't explained that anywhere.

Comment: Fixed it and deleted my comment. I am using Python 2 - the answer you gave Henno was definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`header_hex` is a regular string of lower case ASCII characters and the `decode()` method with `'hex'` argument changes it to a (binary) string (or `bytes` object in Python 3) with bytes `0x93 0xa0` etc. In C it would be an array of unsigned char of length 64 in this case.

This array/byte string of length 64 is then hashed with SHA256 and its result (another binary string of size 32) is again hashed. So `hash` is a string of length 32, or a bytes object of that length in Python 3. Then `encode('hex_codec')` is a synomym for `encode('hex')` (in Python 2); in Python 3, it replaces it (so maybe this code is meant to work in both versions). It outputs an ASCII (lower hex) string again that replaces each raw byte (which is just a small integer) with a two character string that is its hexadecimal representation. So the final bit reverses the double hash and outputs it as hexadecimal, to a form which I usually call "lowercase hex ASCII".

Comment: I've gotten myself confused again. So does hash = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(header_bin).digest()).digest()
output a binary string? and hash.encode('hex_codec')  converts it to hex?

Comment: @BenStolman yes, you last apply the `.digest()` method, and this indeed outputs a binary string, the `encode('hex_codec')` makes it an ASCII string (for "human consumption" ).

Comment: How would you get access to the binary level? It's just a bunch of 1's and 0s', yea?

Comment: @BenStolman You already have access to the binary level when you have a binary string: each byte is just 8 bits. If you want indidual bits you can use & operators etc. to compute them. If you want to print one byte, use the `bin` function which works on integers (and a byte is just a small integer).

Comment: @BenStolman `[bin(i) for i in hash]` if you want to see all bytes as bit strings (in printable form again).

Comment: Would I put that after hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(header_bin).digest()).digest()  ?

Comment: What does i represent? - I would bring this to a chat, but I don't have enough street cred.

Comment: @BenStolman a loop variable for each byte of hash. Could have been named anything